# Three time ViewDidload method is calling

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard, viewcontroller

I am using Two storyboard one Main and another Dashboard.
After successfull response, I am loading LGSideMenu

Issue is DashboardViewController ViewDidLoad is calling 3 times.

```
-(void)loadDashboardController{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Dashboard" bundle:nil];

        UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationController"];
        DashboardViewController *mainViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
        mainViewController.rootViewController = navigationController;
        [mainViewController setupWithPresentationStyle:LGSideMenuPresentationStyleSlideAbove type:0];
        UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window;
        window.rootViewController = mainViewController;
        [UIView transitionWithView:window
                          duration:0.3
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                        animations:nil
                        completion:nil];
    });
}
```

Is any one face this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0):

you should set `rootviewcontroller` only once on window of your application. that's it. other view controller should be pushed on it or you should set as `viewocontrollers` of your `navigation controller`. so only set,

```
  window.rootViewController = mainViewController;

     //or

  window.rootViewController = navigationcontroller;
```